# Django: "AttributeError: type object 'AutoField' has no attribute 'rsplit'" after adding "DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD" to settings.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

I just updated my Django project from 3.1.6 to 3.2.3. After running `python manage.py runserver`, the server ran with these warnings:

```
core.CoreUser: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the CoreConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
```

Then I remembered that I need to add a `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` setting to `settings.py` after updating a project to Django from version < 3.2 to version >= 3.2, so I did:

```py
# settings.py

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = django.db.models.AutoField
```

Then I tried `python manage.py runserver` again, but this time I got a different warning:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Chris\my_project>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... (truncated for brevity)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\my_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 13, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: type object 'AutoField' has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

I thought that something about my migrations or database was causing the issue, so I deleted `db.sqlite3` and all of the app's migrations. Then I ran a fresh `python manage.py makemigrations`, except that caused the same error: `AttributeError: type object 'AutoField' has no attribute 'rsplit'`

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you need to wrap `django.db.models.AutoField` in quotes to make it a string, like this:

```
# settings.py

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

This kind of problem can be a little tricky to figure out, since Django doesn't give you any tips if you use a real import instead of a dotted module path as a string. Just be extra mindful that you are using strings in `settings.py`.